# anchor with #hash go to a wrong place in another page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hash, anchor

I met a issue when use an anchor with hash to navigate to a Microsoft KB, this link [goto leve2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040#gotolevel2)
go to a wrong place in IE but in other browser works fine. I guess this is because of page content changed after page loaded, dose anyone met this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is a window.load and hash parse sequence problem. When other browsers execute onload event handler first and then set hash position while IE does in opposite way.

Note that if you enter in IE's address bar the again, it scrolls to correct position.

Comment: Yes, is there any way to fix this issue except modify this Microsoft KB.

Comment: I don't think so. You can't modify IE (I bet lots of people wish to), or this page.

Comment: Actually, if the document size is unchanged during the window.load event, this issue will disappear.